# Grouping by every n minutes

Tags: c#, linq

I'm playing around with LINQ and I was wondering how easy could it be to group by minutes, but instead of having each minute, I would like to group by every 5 minutes.

For example, currently I have:

```
var q = (from cr in JK_ChallengeResponses
        where cr.Challenge_id == 114
        group cr.Challenge_id 
            by new { cr.Updated_date.Date, cr.Updated_date.Hour, cr.Updated_date.Minute } 
            into g 
        select new {
          Day = new DateTime(g.Key.Date.Year, g.Key.Date.Month, g.Key.Date.Day, g.Key.Hour, g.Key.Minute, 0),
          Total = g.Count()
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Day);
```

[image]

What do I have to do to group my result for each **5 minutes**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To group by `n` of something, you can use the following formula to create "buckets":

```
((int)(total / bucket_size)) * bucket_size
```

This will take the total, divide it, cast to integer to drop off any decimals, and then multiply again, which ends up with multiples of `bucket_size`.  So for instance (`/` is integer division, so casting isn't necessary):

```
group cr.Challenge_id
    by new { cr.Updated_Date.Year, cr.Updated_Date.Month, 
             cr.Updated_Date.Day, cr.Updated_Date.Hour,
             Minute = (cr.Updated_Date.Minute / 5) * 5 }
```

Comment: does this work with LINQ? I'm getting `Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.` as `by new` expects a simple name, not a condition...

Comment: I think you need to give the Minute property a name, e.g. Minute = (cur.Updated_Date.Minute / 5) * 5

Comment: Yes, I missed that part.  I had a name for the property in my test code which worked fine.  I will update.

Comment: works fine in LinqPad, but when using entities, I get `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.` ... so I can't use `Minutes = `

Comment: @balexandre: It's barely translatable to SQL.

Comment: @mellamokb: What is the point to divide by 5 first then multiple by 5?

Comment: @abatishchev: As explained in the post, `/` causes integer division, so if you do integer division and then multiplication by some number `n`, it is the equivalent to rounding down to the nearest multiple of `n`.  Use a concrete example to understand what I mean.  If you take `13 / 5` you get `2`, then take `2 * 5` to get `10`.  Indeed `13` rounded down to the nearest multiple of `5` would be `10`. It's a sort of "hack" for efficiently grouping numbers into `n`-sized buckets :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed that. The code just cached my eye.

Answer (score -1):

//Data comes for every 3 Hours

where (Convert.ToDateTime(capcityprogressrow["Data Captured Date"].ToString()).Date != DateTime.Now.Date || (Convert.ToDateTime(capcityprogressrow["Data Captured Date"].ToString()).Date == DateTime.Now.Date && (Convert.ToInt16(capcityprogressrow["Data Captured Time"])) % 3 == 0))
                                       group capcityprogressrow by new { WCGID = Convert.ToInt32(Conversions.GetIntEntityValue("WCGID", capcityprogressrow)), WCGName = Conversions.GetEntityValue("WIRECENTERGROUPNAME", capcityprogressrow).ToString(), DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(capcityprogressrow["Data Captured Date"]), DueTime = capcityprogressrow["Data Captured Time"].ToString() } into WCGDateGroup

// For orderby with acsending order

```
.OrderBy(x => x.WcgName).ThenBy(x => x.DataCapturedDateTime).ThenBy(x => x.DataCapturedTime).ToList();
```