# How can I group a date column to a less precise format while selecting in Entity Framework or LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, grouping

I am collecting data within every `ten seconds` (`six records` in a `minute`). 
Using `Entity Framework` or `LINQ`, I want to obtain the average of the records within a every minute.
Simply, Date column is in (`%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s`) format, and i want to group by (`%Y.%m.%d %H:%i`) format in `mysql` using `Entity Framework` or `LINQ`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping by every n minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060743/grouping-by-every-n-minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean you have a date time column you can group by the `DateTime` properties `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, and `Minute`.

```
var results = from row in db.SomeTable
              group by new 
              { 
                  row.Date.Year, 
                  row.Date.Month, 
                  row.Date.Day, 
                  row.Date.Hour, 
                  row.Date.Minute 
              } into grp
              select new 
              { 
                  YMDHM = grp.Key
                  SomeAverage = grp.Average(x => x.SomeValueToAverage)
              };
```

Then when you iterate the results you can turn the values in `YMDHM` back into a `DateTime`.  Here's an example where you could turn the results into a `Dictionary`.

```
var dictionaryOfAverages = results.ToDictionary(
    x => new DateTime(x.YMDHM.Year, 
                      x.YMDHM.Month,  
                      x.YMDHM.Day,  
                      x.YMDHM.Hour,  
                      x.YMDHM.Minute,  
                      0), 
    x => x.SomeAverage);
```

On the other hand if you actually mean you are storing the date time in the DB as a formatted string then the following would be what you want

```
var results = from row in db.SomeTable
              group by new row.Date.SubString(0, 16) into grp
              select new 
              { 
                  YMDHM = grp.Key
                  SomeAverage = grp.Average(x => x.SomeValueToAverage)
              };
```

This is assuming that your string formatted dates look like "2013.05.08 07:25:33"  If the format isn't fixed width with leading zeros for month, day, and/or hour you'd have to do something like `row.Date.SubString(0, row.Date.Length - 3)` instead